# ¿Cómo juntar dos listas en Java?

Tags: java, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Necesito crear un método que junte el contenidos de dos listas en Java, Si mis listas son las siguientes: List 1: [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
List 2: [4, 6, 8, 10]

Se espera que la salida sea de la siguiente forma: Concatenate sorted lst1, lst2: [0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10]

Mi método main es:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> lst1 = new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<Integer> lst2 = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0, j = 4; i < 10; i += 3, j += 2) {
        lst1.add(i);
        lst1.add(i + 1);
        lst2.add(j);
    }
System.out.println("**** Testing concatenate sorted ****");
    System.out.println("Concatenate sorted lst1, lst2: " + ListUtils.concatenateSorted(lst1, lst2));
```

Cree el siguiente método para poder juntar las listas, el método es el siguiente:

```
 public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> LinkedList<T> concatenateSorted(LinkedList<T> lst1, 
 LinkedList<T> lst2) {
    LinkedList<T> newLst = new LinkedList<>(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < lst1.size(); i++) {
         for(int j = 0; j < lst2.size();j++) {
            while(i < lst1.size() && j < lst2.size()) {




            }

         }
    }   



    return newLst;
}
```

Pero luego de esto no se cómo vas seguir, alguien podría apoyarme con una solución ?

Estas son algunos apuntes que pude hacer para tratar de llegar a una solución

```
// Usa dos contadores, una para recorrer lst1, y otro para lst2
// Mientras tengas elementos por procesar en ambas listas (i < lst1.size() y j < lst2.size())
// Compara elementos de ambas listas (Usa el método compareTo para hacerlo)
// Agrega el mas pequeño, ya sea lst1 o lst2
// y actualiza el contador que corresponda, sumándole 1

// En caso de que las listas sean de tamaño diferente
// Revisa si todavia quedan elementos en lst1 o lst2 y agregalos
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `Stream.concat()` para unir ambas listas y  `Collections.sort()` para ordenar los valores, de esta forma

```
   List<Integer> listaFinal = Stream.concat(lst1.stream(), lst2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
   Collections.sort(listaFinal);
```

Inicialmente tendrías los valores de las listas como:

```
lst1: [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]
lst2: [4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Al unirlas tendrías como resultado:

```
listaFinal: [0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Perfecto entonces haré la prueba de eso, muchísimas gracias